# Date saved 1 day earlier than in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with a `booking_date` and when I fill in the form with a date of 1 March 2016, these are the parameters sent:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "pturnover"=>{"booking_date(3i)"=>"1", "booking_date(2i)"=>"3", "booking_date(1i)"=>"2016"}, "commit"=>"Opslaan", "id"=>"5"}
```

But when I look in the database after saving, it is saved as 29 february 2016:

```
=> #<Pturnover id: 5, booking_date: "2016-02-29 23:00:00"
```

How is this possible, is it related to timezone or something?

Comment: `is it related to timezone or something?` possibly `yes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails saves datetimes in database with `utc` timezone by default. Datetime conversion from/to strings may take into account local timezone, either one of the OS or set manually. Conversion between local and `utc` is a probable reason of the discrepancy you are seeing.

As timezone handling in Rails is a sizeable topic, it's advisable to approach it in some depth. Here are some relevant resources:

[RailsCasts #106 Time Zones (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised)

[The Exhaustive Guide to Rails Time Zones](http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/)

[Working with time zones in Ruby on Rails](https://www.varvet.com/blog/working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails/)

[It's About Time (Zones)](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/its-about-time-zones)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the inputed time before saving or you can convert that time when showing in your show page.Conversion may looks like below :

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Asia/Tokyo").local(your_inputed_time_here)
```

Hope that helps.